# Build NodeList of multiple element types in one line?

Tags: javascript, dom, concatenation, nodelist

I'm trying to declare an array of all form elements on the page (inputs, selects, textareas, and buttons) in one line of code without any helper JS libraries.

So far the best I can come up with is this ugly nonsense:

```
var formElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('select'))).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'))).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button')));
```

Can anyone help me make a version of this line that sucks less?

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll` if you don't need IE7.

Comment: Can't think of one offhand, but `["input", "select", "textarea", "button"].map(function(e) {return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(e))}).reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b)})​` probably sucks just a little bit less.  At least it removes most of the duplicate code. :) Still ugly, though.

Comment: You could shorthand the calls as follows: `var a=Array.prototype.slice, c='call', o='concat', d=document, g='getElementsByTagName', formElements = a[c](d[g]('input'))[o](a[c](d[g]('textarea')))`